# статическое выделение памяти на C#

Tags: c#

Есть ли статическое выделение памяти на C#, как например на С++, например в плюсах массивы заинитить динамически, можно просто статически, в шарпее даже в туторах не объясняется этот момент, вдруг я хочу выделить для переменной место в стеке, а не в куче , и вообще применимы ли термины стек, куча к платформе Net

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc

Comment: В C# вообще можно не знать, как там аллокейшн памяти работает, и не париться, вообще. Вас интересует конкретный пример? Покажите код C++ и код C#, делающий то же самое. Тогда можно будет ответить и выяснить, как там именно оно работает. Для меня `int[] a = new int[100];` - это факт выделения памяти под массив на 100 интов.

Comment: `...например в плюсах массивы заинитить динамически, можно просто статически, в шарпее даже в туторах не объясняется этот момент...` потому что это мало кому нужно кто пишет на `C#`. Разные языки, для разных задач. Ваше заявление подобно тому, если заявить, что на электрогитаре я могу такой рифф забубенить, а ты на своем рояле даже ничего подобного сыграть не сможешь - потому гитара круче рояля, смешно..